# Handling 302 Redirect in Tomcat's web.xml

Tags: apache, tomcat, web.xml, http-redirect, openid-connect

Is it possible to handle 302 redirect in web.xml using `<error-page`> and `<error-code`> tags?

For example,

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>302</error-code>
    <location>index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

This code is not working. Am I missing anything or handling 3xx isn't possible in error-code tags?

Upon session timeout due to inactivity, the webserver would be redirected to OIDC Authorization server for getting the new token. This redirection is taken by a pom.xml dependency that's transparent to the developer. This doesn't work with frames. To make it work, I want to intercept the redirect in web.xml and redirect the request to a custom page that would open a new window and make a request to the authorization server for a fresh token. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Code 302 is not an error, thus no.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is there any other way to achieve the end result which I mentioned in my question?

Comment: Implementing a Filter would do the job, by catching the response and checking if it is a redirection, and then replacing the response content by yours.